# Webcam testing application?

Tags: windows-xp, webcam

Does anybody know a simple, one-click application to

- see the current image on the webcam
- check the volume level

on Windows XP?

I know this can be found in various ways and places throughout the system but I am looking for a one-click icon that can be put into the quick launch bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take a still image with **MS Paint** (**File** > **From Scanner or Camera...** - this will get you a live camera preview, without sound).

if you want to do a quick recording to check the volume level of the microphone, you can use **Windows Movie Maker** (not all versions of Movie Maker support capture from camera, this [portable version](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk) does).

if you're looking for something more specific:

**[WebCam Monitor](http://www.deskshare.com/help/WCM/StartingStoppingDevicePreviews.aspx)** provides an intuitive user interface to preview the video from your camera.  The Preview screen can be used effectively to position your webcam to get the best results while monitoring.

*WebCam Monitor is shareware ($69.95), try before you buy.*

Comment: MS Paint does seem to offer the option, but doesn't give me a live picture (Windows 7, camera definitely works). Webcam monitor looks interesting, thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: windows 7? you tag says XP

Comment: Sorry, I meant the tool is intended to run on an XP machine, I just took a peek on my 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

[Cheese](http://projects.gnome.org/cheese/) comes to mind, its for Gnome, but it's made in Mono so maybe it also works on Windows with .Net